# React - how to render content from JSON file?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

How do I go about displaying the JSON file data properly in react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You effectively just want to pull the *values* of the object here, you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) in most modern browsers (unless you are using IE, which if you are I feel your pain)

```
Object.values(data).forEach(x => console.log(x.name))
```

To give you a working example in React:

```
import data from "./data.json"

function renderLinks() {
  const records = Object.values(data);
  return (
    <ul>
      {records.map((x, i) => <li key={i}><a href="#">{x.name}</a></li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: I see. And I want to embed each of these names in a link, I can do that using Object.values() correct?

Comment: @DarrelGulseth yes you can, instead of `forEach` you can simply map the result out e.g. `Object.values(data).map(x => <a href="#">{x.name}</a>)`

Comment: @James Stay happy :)

Comment: @James Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys()` and then map name property

```js
import data from './data.json'


// in render function, jsx

{Object.keys(data).map(key => <span key={key}>{data[key].name}</span>)}
```

Comment: FWIW when rendering lists you should provide a `key`, this code would flag a warning in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Object.keys(data) gives ["1", "2" ....];

So you can loop through keys

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){
  console.log(data[key].name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order you can use `Object.keys()`

```js
Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    console.log(data[key].name); 
});
```

Otherwise, if you do care about the order, use a for loops and cast the integer as a string.

```js
for(int i = 0; i < Object.size(data); i++){
    console.log(data[i.toString()].name); 
}
```